How do you configure Android Studio to be able to visualise the contents of .pb (protocol buffer) files
My current android project utilises google protobuf files and i would like to check the contents of the files inside Android Studio.
i am using the following version of android studio:-
Android Studio Jellyfish | 2023.3.1
Build #AI-233.14808.21.2331.11709847, built on April 12, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.10+0-17.0.10b1087.21-11572160 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 14.4.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 3072M
Cores: 16
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
  ide.experimental.ui=true
Non-Bundled Plugins:
  idea.plugin.protoeditor (233.14808.14)

i have installed the protocol buffer plugin, however when i attempt to view the .pb file contents i get the following message.

how do i attach a schema?
this is the version of the plugin i am employing

When i go to settings this is what i see

how do i achieve my desired result of being able to make the .pb file contents readable?

Please provide a link to the plugin as I'm unfamiliar with it (is it this?). Generally (!) Protocol Buffer plugins allow you to edit protocol buffer source files (schema) but they don't permit unmarshaling of binary-encoded protocol buffer messages (created by the schemas and often in files named {something}.pb) which is, I think, what you're trying to do. This would be useful functionality (and it's possible the plugin does provide it) but, if so, it would likely want a reference to the schema to correctly unmarshal the message.
